# vb6 connecting to mysql :[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc

I switched to a new PC, Win7, 64bit(my previous PC is 32bit). My VB6 doesn't seem to be able to connect to MySQL. I have tested my code at 2 other PC(running on 64bit) and they work, mine keep giving me the above error. I have installed the ODBC Connector to 5.3.10 version, The following code is definitely correct coz I run it on 2 other PC. I am not sure which references I am missing. Is there something I need to do with system DNS, 32bit or 64bit? In the 32 bit system DNS -> Add, I have have the 5.3 Unicode and 5.3 Ansi but not at the 64Bit. My other PC got both. I tried to uninstall the reinstall the unicode but it only goes to 32bit system DNS. I have run out of idea, please help.

```
sDatabase = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=192.168.0.221;Port=3307;UID=root;Password=Pass;Database=Database ;OPTION=3;"

Set gConn = New ADODB.Connection
gConn.Open sDatabase
```

## My ODBC Connector

[image: Pic]

## My System DNS,64Bit

[image: Pic]

## In the Add, I can't find the 5.3 unicode or 5.3 Ansi

[image: pic]

## My System DNS,32Bit

[image: Pic]

## In the Add, I have the 5.3 unicode and 5.3 Ansi

[image: pic]

## VB6->Project-> References

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Installed both x64 (64 bit) and x86 (32 bit) Connector/ODBC. The more the merrier.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html